# clearTimeout doesn't clear the timeout variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have an application that needs to be timed out after 28 minutes. It will show the jQuery dialog for 2 minutes. If the user clicks "Ok" within the two minutes the timer refreshes to 28 minutes and when the count down reaches 0 minutes it should show the jQuery dialog again.

The issue is when I debug, I see the timeout variable is not clearing out the timeout. After I click "Ok", the timer resets to 28 minutes but the setTimeout doesn't show the dialog again when the count down reaches 0 minutes.

Here is my code:

```
var timeout;
function timer() {
countDownDate = 0;
    console.log("Hello");
    countDownDate = 0;
    var timeExpires = new Date().getTime();
    countDownDate = timeExpires + 1680000;
    now = 0;
    distance = 0;
    if(timeout){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function () {

        // Get todays date and time
         now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
         distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        if (distance < 0) {
        if ($("#alert").length) {
            var title;
            if ($("#alert span").length) {
                title = $("#alert span").text();
            }
            $("#alert div").dialog({
                title: title,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                        var foo = $(this);
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timer();
                        foo.dialog('close');
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                      esriId.destroyCredentials();
                      window.location.replace(redirect_uri);
                    }
                  }/*,
                open: function() {
                    var foo = $(this);
                    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        foo.dialog('close');
                        esriId.destroyCredentials();
                        window.location.replace(redirect_uri);
                    }, 120000);
                },*/

            });
            }
            timeout = setTimeout($("#alert div").dialog("open"), 120000);
            clearInterval(x);
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

Here is the HTML div for the alert:

```
<div id="alert" style="display:none">
            <span>You will be signed out</span>
            <div>You will be signed out due to inactivity on the page. If you wish to stay on the page, please press 'Ok'</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Look at your setTimeout line.... you are not using it correctly

Comment: How do I use it differently? I saw this example on another stack overflow post.

Comment: The `setTimeout()` function's first argument needs to be a function *reference*. You are calling `.dialog('open')` *immediately* and passing its return value to `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written,

- `setTimeout()` command is wrongly constructed.
- you appear to want to open the dialog when the 28 minutes expire and close it automatically after a further 2 minutes if OK is not clicked; but you are using that 2 minute timer to *open* the dialog, not to *close* it.
- it's difficult to see the wood for the trees inside `timer()`.

`timer()` can be simplified by :

- defining the dialog setup in a function, outside `timer()`.
- defining the countdown timer calcs/display in a function, outside `timer()`.
- introducing a third timer to manage the 28 minute duration - this avoids the need to test `if (distance < 0)` etc in the time display function.

Here's the revised code :

```
// set up the dialog
function showDialog(callback) {
    $("#alert div").dialog('destroy').dialog({
        title: $("#alert span").length ? $("#alert span").text() : '---',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback('ok')
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                // $(this).dialog('close'); // ?
                callback('cancel');
            }
        }
    }).dialog('open');
}

// function for calculating and displayig the countdown values
function displayCountdown(t) {
    var distance = Math.max(0, t - Date.now());
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    // ... display days, hours, minutes, seconds somewhere
}

// object which defines the three timers
var timers = {
    'ticker':     { 'ref': null, 't': 1000 }, // 1 second
    'stopTicker': { 'ref': null, 't': 1680000}, // 28 minutes
    'cancelDialog': { 'ref': null, 't': 120000 } // 2 minutes
}

function redirect() {
    esriId.destroyCredentials();
    window.location.replace(redirect_uri);
}

// 
function timer() {
    clearInterval(timers.ticker.ref);
    clearTimeout(timers.stopTicker.ref);
    clearTimeout(timers.cancelDialog.ref);
    timers.stopTicker.ref = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(timers.ticker.ref);
        showDialog(function(outcome) {
            if(outcome === 'ok') {
                timer();
            } else {
                redirect();
            }
        });
        timers.cancelDialog.ref = setTimeout(redirect, timers.cancelDialog.t);
    }, timers.stopTicker.t);

    timers.ticker.ref = setInterval(displayCountdown.bind(null, Date.now() + timers.stopTicker.t), timers.ticker.t);
};
```

Note that `redirect()` will be called in two possible ways :

1. in response to the dialog being cancelled.
2. in response to expiry of the 2 minutes.

The callback passed to `showDialog()` isn't strictly necessary but allows the dialog to be completely agnostic of the consequences of its outcome. All that logic is in the caller, `timer()`.

---

Another, arguably cleaner, approach is to promisify the dialog.

Here, everything remains the same as above except `showDialog()` and `timer()`.

```
// set up a promisified dialog
function showDialog() {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        $("#alert div").dialog('destroy').dialog({
            'title': $("#alert span").length ? $("#alert span").text() : '---',
            'modal': true,
            'buttons': {
                'Ok': dfrd.resolve, // yay!
                'Cancel': dfrd.reject // yay!
            }
        }).dialog('open');
    }).always(function() {
        $("#alert div").dialog('close');
    });
}

function timer() {
    clearTimeout(timers.ticker.ref);
    clearTimeout(timers.stopTicker.ref);
    clearTimeout(timers.cancelDialog.ref);
    timers.stopTicker.ref = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(timers.ticker.ref);
        $.Deferred(function(dfrd) { // "race" pattern
            showDialog().then(dfrd.resolve, dfrd.reject);
            timers.cancelDialog.ref = setTimeout(dfrd.reject, timers.cancelDialog.t);
        }).then(timer, redirect); // yay-yay!
    }, timers.stopTicker.t);

    timers.ticker.ref = setInterval(displayCountdown.bind(null, Date.now() + timers.stopTicker.t), timers.ticker.t);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
function open() {
  $("#alert div").dialog("open");
 }

 timeout = setTimeout(open, 120000);
```

Comment: This still doesn't get the alert to show the second time around. It shows once, I click ok, timer refreshes but when it reaches 0, it calls the setTimeout again but doesn't show the alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that once you instantiate a `.dialog()`, it uses the `span` and `div`.

So you got to refresh those.
I made it work in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yXRmdB?editors=1011). *(I shortened the times for test purposes)*

Before the `timer()` function, add this:

```
var alertHTML = $("#alert").html();
```

Then, in the function, the trick is here:

```
var title;
if ($("#alert div").length) {
  console.log("alert is present");
}else{
  console.log("alert is missing");
  $("#alert").html(alertHTML);
}
title = $("#alert span").text();
```